# SpatialPolygonsDataFrame error in R when attempting to add order

Tags: r, spatial-data-frame

I am attempting to create a choropleth by following Geospatial Health Data by Paula Moraga, Chapter 15. The data can be downloaded from the [book info page](https://www.paulamoraga.com/book-geospatial-info/). It is the Chapter 15 data from the DOWNLOAD APPDIR FOLDER link.

The choropleth I am trying to duplicate can be found in [section 15.7.3](https://www.paulamoraga.com/book-geospatial/sec-shinyexample.html) The code I am using is directly from the text (with appropriate changes for my working directory):

```
data <- read.csv("data/data.csv")

map <- readOGR("data/fe_2007_39_county/fe_2007_39_county.shp")

datafiltered <- data[which(data$year == 1980), ]

ordercounties <- match(map@data$NAME, datafiltered$county)

map@data <- datafiltered[ordercounties, ]
```

However, the map@data results in an error:

```
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  c("assignment of an object of class “sf” is not valid for @‘data’ in an object of class “SpatialPolygonsDataFrame”; is(value, \"data.frame\") is not TRUE", "assignment of an object of class “data.frame” is not valid for @‘data’ in an object of class “SpatialPolygonsDataFrame”; is(value, \"data.frame\") is not TRUE")
```

How do I resolve this error?

Using Chris's advice below, I tried a new terminal but that didn't help. Running `sf:sf_extSoftVersion()` gave me:

```
          GEOS           GDAL         proj.4 GDAL_with_GEOS     USE_PROJ_H           PROJ 
       "3.9.1"        "3.2.1"        "7.2.1"         "true"         "true"        "7.2.1"
```

Problem still unresolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I don't reproduce your error. What is the output of `sf::sf_extSoftVersion()`, list `library(rgdal)` above. Probably re-start in a new terminal session (which may be voodoo...but can't hurt)

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your response. I tried a new terminal session and got the same error. The output of `sf::sf_extSoftVersion()` is:

`          GEOS           GDAL         proj.4 GDAL_with_GEOS     USE_PROJ_H           PROJ 
           "3.9.1"        "3.2.1"        "7.2.1"         "true"                     "true"               "7.2.1"`

Comment: And I'm confounded. sf::sf_extSoftVersion()
                 GEOS                  GDAL                proj.4 
             "3.10.2" "3.5.0dev-af52706a15"               "8.2.1" 
       GDAL_with_GEOS            USE_PROJ_H                  PROJ 
               "true"                "true"               "8.2.1" . Hard to break something without an error, but someone smarter will come along. These extSoftVersion output are easier to quickly assess above, rather than in comments, so you might put your's up there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Chris. I added the output above.

Comment: I also do **not** get any error. However two comments: What packages have you loaded and in what order? Your error refers to `sf`, but code snippet in your question should not be using `sf` at all. Only `rgdal` for the `readOGR` function.

And be aware that the R-spatial collection of software has undergone substantial changes over the last few years. The `rgdal` package as well as `sp`, used in this example, will soon be deprecated, so the author of the book will need to rewrite her exercises...

Comment: See this [blog post](https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html) for details about the deprecated packages.

Comment: @Micha Thank you for your response. Since rgdal is being deprecated, I'll look around for a different way to go.